# How to style pagination bar in angular project

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

how i can style pager in angular inside TS file or HTML file without scss with this code

[image]

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center"   *ngIf="totalCount && totalCount > 0">
    <pagination
    [totalItems]="totalCount"
    [boundaryLinks]="true"
    (pageChanged)="onPagerChange($event)"
    [itemsPerPage]="pageSize"
    previousText="&lsaquo;"
    nextText="&rsaquo;"
    firstText="&laquo;"
     lastText="&raquo;"
     pageBtnClass="black-background" >
    </pagination>
</div>
```

i try with make new file scss file and add my style
but that not working i need solution soon as possible

Comment: It's impossible know what "pagination" are you using. Please edit your question indicate the library you're using.